# How to set CssClass on button in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0

I have a ButtonColumn in a DataGrid:

```
<asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Edit" />
```

How do I set it's CSS class?

The only way I can see to do it, is hooking to the RowDataBound event:

```
Protected Sub dgSchedule_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgSchedule.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        DirectCast(e.Item.Cells(6).Controls(0), Button).CssClass = "confirmButton"

    End If
End Sub
```

I just feel like there must be a neater way. What happens if I add/remove columns, I'll have to come back here and remember to change column 6...

I tried using a `TemplateColumn` and a usual `asp:Button` - This worked, but then clicking it did not fire the ItemCommand event of the grid which I need to fire.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have resolved this by using a GridView instead of a DataGrid. Actually not sure why I used a DataGrid in the first place.

This gives an additional property `ControlStyle-CssClass`

e.g.

```
<asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" ControlStyle-CssClass="confirmButton" />
```

Comment: Thank you. 9 years later and this answer is still useful for legacy apps.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options:

**1. You can set the CssClass property of the ButtonColumn:**

```
<asp:ButtonColumn CssClass="myStyle" ...></asp:ButtonColumn>
```

This will render the following HTML:

```
<td class="myStyle">
    <input type=button name=select ...>
</td>
```

As you can see, the CSS class is actually applied to the containing  element. To style the column, do this:

```
.myClass
{
   /*Your style attributes go here*/
}
```

And to style the actual button, do this in your CSS:

```
.myClass INPUT
{
   /*Your style attributes go here*/
}
```

---

**2. Alternatively, you can use a TemplateColumn instead of a ButtonColumn and set the CssClass property of the nested button control:**

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat=server Text="Delete" CssClass="myClass" CommandName="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

The CSS for this is just as you would expect:

```
.myClass
{
   /*Your style attributes go here*/
}
```

Comment: ButtonColumn doesn't have an attribute called CssClass (compiler: "Type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonColumn' does not have a public property named 'CssClass'). I did also explain in question why I didn't want to use a TemplateColumn. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. The ButtonColumn property you need to set is ItemStyle-CssClass. And you'll notice in my TemplateColumn code that I have shown you how to fire an item command from a button.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. I tried ItemStyle-CssClass but it doesn't style the button only the cell. Have resolved with a GridView but thank you for answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stick with DataGrid rather than use GridView, one way to solve this problem is to setup an `OnItemDataBound` event.

```
OnItemDataBound="mydatagrid_ItemDataBound"
```

Then in the code behind you can attached the CSS class to the button as follows:

```
//ON DATA BIND
protected void mydatagrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer) {
        Button myButton= (Button)e.Item.Cells[5].Controls[0];
        myButton.Attributes["class"] = "buttonClass";   
    }
}
```