# Javascript function and <asp:Buttoncolumn>

Tags: c#, asp.net

my .cs file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string arg = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
        string val= Request.Form["EVENTARGUMENT"];


        if (arg == "Delete")
        {
            DeleteRecord();

        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
             {

            PopulateDelete();
        }


    }
```

and my aspx page Javascript method is

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var fRet;

        fRet = confirm('Do you want to Delete the record?');
        if (fRet == true)
            __doPostBack('Delete', fRet);
        return true;
    }
```

Gridview in aspx page is

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"         BackColor="#DEBA84"
        BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        BorderStyle="None" CellSpacing="2"
        CssClass="HCStyle" ondeletecommand="dgProducts_DeleteCommand" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SerialNo" HeaderText="SerialNo">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>

            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Organization" HeaderText="Organization">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>

            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Origin" HeaderText="Origin">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
            </asp:BoundColumn>

             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Service" HeaderText="Services">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
            </asp:BoundColumn>

             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
            </asp:BoundColumn>

             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Established" HeaderText="Established">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
            </asp:BoundColumn>
             <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete"  HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:ButtonColumn>
```

According to this when ever i click on the Delete Button in gridview a javascript text box will be shown, if i click yes on JS textbox Then DeleteRecord() Method should be called, but i am getting the arg value as "dgProducts$ctl02$ctl00" ,, How can i call the DeleteRecords() Method...plz help meeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemtemplatefield with button to achive your purpose. Check this link.[Execute Javascript function from GridView ItemTemplate button click ASP.NET Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868454/execute-javascript-function-from-gridview-itemtemplate-button-click-asp-net-web)

Answer (score -1):

**Add one class to ButtonColumn** 

`<asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete"  HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete" ControlStyle-CssClass="deleteButton" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:ButtonColumn>`

**Change javascript function as below**

`$(document).ready(function() {

     $('.deleteButton').click(function() { 
     return confirm('Do you want to Delete the record?'); 
    }); 
    });`

Comment: ButtonColumn Does not have a property called "ControlStyle-CssClass"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351064/how-to-set-cssclass-on-button-in-datagrid